# How to list and display the items that they were tagged by taxonomy vocabulary with view module in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I am trying to list a certain taxonomy vocabulary's term and the items(clients that we worked) that they were tagged by those terms.

The taxonomy vocabulary is "fields" and fields has different terms such as "Web development, app development, game development, data science, financial software, communications" and each field tags clients. For instance, web development has a client of "saiba labs","tribeca hub" and app development has "saiba labs" again and "trel restaurants" and game development "saiba labs" and "fry mobile".

I want them to be listed like this:

```
    Web Development
      Saiba Labs
      Tribeca Hub

    App Development
      Saiba Labs
      Trel Restaurants

    Game Development
      Saiba Labs
      Fry Mobile
```

But so far What i have been able to display is:

```
    Web Development
      Saiba Labs
    Web Development 
      Tribeca Hub
    App Development 
      Saiba Labs
    App Development
      Trel Restaurants
    Game Development
      Saiba Labs
    Game Development 
      Fry Mobile
```

I am trying to do this in Drupal 7. What I have done so far are:

1-I created a view page(using view module).

2-I created a url through through that view page( something like /fields-we-worked.

3-FORMAT: Unformatted list

4-SHOW: Fields

5-FIELDS: (term) Taxonomy term:Name
  Content:Title

6-FILTER CRITERIA
  (term)Taxonomy term:Vocabulary(=fields)

7-CONTEXTUAL FILTERS:(term)Taxonomy term:Name

8-RELATIONSHIP:Content:Taxonomy terms on node

Has anyone encountered issue like this? I would appreciate any help. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score -1):

You should try editing the template that outputs the form.